# How to display specific country map and display dots on specific cities?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

the purpose is to display the map of Saudi Arabia and for each city on the map put some red dots and green dots, and each dot refer to a citizen, when i click on the dot popup appears, please tell me where to start, and what can help me to accomplish that.

Comment: Do you want to display one dot for each citizen? Or one dot per city and its size varies based on the number of inhabitants of that city?

Comment: For dots use markers.  For popups use infowindows.  Start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @pascal, I want to display dynamic number for citizens in each city, but first how to display map for saudi arabia country with the cities for the country ?

Answer (score -1):

Considering that you want to create a website. Integrate the google map for Saudi Arabia in your website. That way you will get the map in your website. Google for map integration in website.